# Oracle MAF : (Signature Capture) Calling a javascript function from Managed Bean

Tags: javascript, java, oracle-maf

I'm following [this tutorial](https://blogs.oracle.com/mobile/entry/signature_capture_demo) to get signature capture functionality in Oracle MAF application.

When I tried with simple POC as explained in the tutorial, I made it work with out any issues. Same logic I have integrated into my project.

---

Following are the settings I have done for integration,

- I have included `js and css` file into `maf-feature.xml` under Task
  flow definition (where i'm having `amx` page).
- I have defined scope of the bean as `pageFlow` inside
  `XXXXX-task-flow.xml` file instead of `adfc-mobile-config.xml` like
  below,

  ```
  <managed-bean id="__20">
    <managed-bean-name>signatureCapture</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>package.SignatureCapture</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>pageFlow</managed-bean-scope>
  </managed-bean>
  ```
- when I'm calling `fetchHandler` and `cleaHandler` method using below
  `commandButton`, it is calling method without Fail.

From the method, below statement is not triggering JavaScript

**In fetchHandler method:**

```
AdfmfContainerUtilities.invokeContainerJavaScriptFunction(AdfmfJavaUtilities.getActiveContextId(), "doFetch",
                                                              new Object[] { });
```

**In clearHandler method:**

```
AdfmfContainerUtilities.invokeContainerJavaScriptFunction(AdfmfJavaUtilities.getActiveContextId(), "doClear",
                                                              new Object[] { });
```

---

Below is the JavaScript (`MyFile.js`) for you reference,

```
(function () {

    // This method clears the signature area
    doClear = function () {
    alert("Clear function called.!");
        var sigElement = document.getElementById("sig");
        if (sigElement == null)
            alert("sigElement not found");
        var sig = $(sigElement);
        sig.signature('clear');
        adf.mf.api.invokeMethod("package.SignatureCapture", "FetchCallback", "", onInvokeSuccess, onFail);
    };

    // This method gets the signature as a JSON string.  As an example, it does an alert of the string and then sends it to a Java handler for further processing
    doFetch = function () {
    alert("Fetch function called.!");
        var sigElement = document.getElementById("sig");
        if (sigElement == null)
            alert("sigElement not found");
        var sig = $(sigElement);
        var fetchData = sig.signature('toJSON');
        adf.mf.api.invokeMethod("package.SignatureCapture", "FetchCallback", fetchData, onInvokeSuccess, onFail);
    };

    function onInvokeSuccess(param) {
    alert("onInvokeSuccess");
    };

    function onFail() {
        alert("It failed");
    };

})();
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated. Please comment below, if you need any more details regarding this.

Comment: Instead of AdfmfJavaUtilities.getActiveContextId(), try to use your feature ID (as a string).

Comment: Thanks, Now I can able to call the JavaScript. But why 'AdfmfJavaUtilities.getActiveContextId()' is not working as expected, when I try to print the value it is giving page definition file name. Eg : I'm having signature feature in 'signature.amx' and my page definition is 'signaturePageDef.xml' then 'AdfmfJavaUtilities.getActiveContextId()' is printing 'signaturePageDef' as output. What is the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `AdfmfJavaUtilities.getActiveContextId()`, try to use your feature ID (as a string).

From the Oracle documentation ([click](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/maf213/mobile/api-ref/oracle/adfmf/framework/api/AdfmfContainerUtilities.html#invokeContainerJavaScriptFunction-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object:A-)):

```
public static Object invokeContainerJavaScriptFunction(String featureId,
                                                       String methodName,
                                                       Object[] args)
```

**Parameters:**

- featureId: The id of the feature on which to invoke the method
- methodName:  method name
- args: array of arguments to be passed to
  method

**Returns:**

- a JSON object

So like you can see/said yourself `AdfmfJavaUtilities.getActiveContextId()` doesn't return the featureID but the name of the current feature's active EL context ([click](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/maf213/mobile/api-ref/oracle/adfmf/framework/api/AdfmfJavaUtilities.html#getActiveContextId--))

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. :)